# Entity Framework ModelBuilder in two different files?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext

Is it possible to have ModelBuilders for Entities to be in different files? We are trying to separate automatic scaffolding from database, and have certain manual customization also.

This is what I am attempting, receiving error below,

**File 1:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyMailingAddress>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.LkAddressType)
        .WithMany(p => p.PropertyMailingAddress)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.LkAddressTypeId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_PropertyMailingAddress_LK_AddressTypeId");
```

**File 2:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyMailingAddress>(entity =>
{

    entity.HasOne(d => d.LkSourceOfAddress)
        .WithMany(p => p.PropertyMailingAddress)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.LkSourceOfAddressId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_PropertyMailingAddress_LK_SourceOfAddressId");
```

> Error CS1501  No overload for method 'Entity' takes 2 arguments

Is it possible to have partial class methodology for this?

Comment: Why not? Use an extension method.

Comment: hi @bolkay can you provide in code example, and I can send points? not sure how to implement extension method for this question topic thanks

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a file per Entity then, instead of using the Model Builder, use the `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. Create a class implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` per entity. For example:

```
public class PropertyMailingAddressConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PropertyMailingAddress>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PropertyMailingAddress> builder)
  {
     builder
       .HasOne(d => d.LkAddressType);
       .WithMany(p => p.PropertyMailingAddress);
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.LkAddressTypeId)
       .HasConstraintName("FK_PropertyMailingAddress_LK_AddressTypeId");
  }
}
```

The default conventions apply the same way, so a property called Id will automatically be mapped as Primary Key and so on.

You then need to tell Entity Framework to load the entity configurations from the files found in a given `Assembly`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
      .ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the dbcontext class to `partial`, creating the partial class in two files, and then defining a method in one of the files to pass the `ModelBuilder` parameters.

For details, please refer to the following.

File1:

```
  public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<PropertyMailingAddress> PropertyMailingAddress{ get; set; } 

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyMailingAddress>(entity =>
            {
              entity.HasOne(d => d.LkAddressType)
                    .WithMany(p => p.PropertyMailingAddress)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.LkAddressTypeId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_PropertyMailingAddress_LK_AddressTypeId");
            });  
        }
    }
```

File2:

```
     public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
        {
            partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
               modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyMailingAddress>(entity =>
               {    

                  entity.HasOne(d => d.LkSourceOfAddress)
                        .WithMany(p => p.PropertyMailingAddress)
                        .HasForeignKey(d => d.LkSourceOfAddressId)

 .HasConstraintName("FK_PropertyMailingAddress_LK_SourceOfAddressId");
               });
            }           
        }
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52186104/12884742).

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why you want to have separate configuration file for a single entity. However, based on what you have provided, you can do this:

```
public partial static class MyExtensions
{
 public static void ConfigureMyEntity(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
.HasOne<Other>()
.WithMany()
....
}
}
```

If you want to define configurations for separate entities, there are cleaner ways to do that.