# EF Core InMemoryDatabase - How to test with Keyless Entity (mapped to Sql View) - XUnit

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

Environment: `.Net Core 3.1` REST API / `EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 3.1.6` / `XUnit 2.4.1`

In a Database First Setup I have a model mapped to a **Sql View**.
During Code Generation (with `EF Core PowerTools 2.4.51`) this entity is marked in `DbContext` with `.HasNoKey()`

When I try to test the endpoint accessing the `DbSet` mapped to the **Sql View** it throws exception:
`Unable to track an instance of type '*' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.`

Follows some code snippets with highlights of what I have tries so far.

Auto generated **DbContext**: `ViewDemoAccountInfo` is the entity mapped to a **Sql View**. Other entities are mapped to regular **Sql Tables**

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace Demo.Data.Entities
{
    public partial class DemoDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DemoDbContext(){}

        public DemoDbContext(DbContextOptions<DemoDbContext> options): base(options){}

        public virtual DbSet<ViewDemoAccountInfo> ViewDemoAccountInfo { get; set; }
        
        // multiple other entities

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ViewDemoAccountInfo>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToView("ViewDemoAccountInfo");

                entity.Property(e => e.AccountType).IsUnicode(false);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Attempt #1**:
**The test**

```
public class MyIntegrationTests : BaseIntegrationTest {
    // throws "Unable to track an instance of type 'ViewDemoAccountInfo' 
    // because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked."
    [Fact]
    public async Task SetupData_WhenKeylessEntity_ThenShouldNotThrow() {
        using (var scope = _testServer.Host.Services.CreateScope()) {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DemoDbContext>();

            await dbContext.ViewDemoAccountInfo.AddAsync(MockedAccountInfo); // setup some data
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        var endpointUrl = $"{ControllerRootUrl}/account-info";
        var response = await _testClient.GetAsync(endpointUrl);

        // Assertions
    }
}
```

**Helpers**

```
public class BaseIntegrationTest {
    protected readonly HttpClient _testClient;
    protected readonly TestServer _testServer;

    public BaseIntegrationTest() {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Test")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) => {
                config.ConfigureSettings(builderContext.HostingEnvironment);
            });

        builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
            services.ConfigureInMemoryDatabases(new InMemoryDatabaseRoot());
        });

        builder.UseStartup<Startup>();

        _testServer = new TestServer(builder);
        _testClient = _testServer.CreateClient();
    }
}

// Regular DbContext
internal static class IntegrationExtensions {
    public static void ConfigureInMemoryDatabases(this IServiceCollection services, InMemoryDatabaseRoot memoryDatabaseRoot) {
        services.AddDbContext<DemoDbContext>(options => 
                 options.UseInMemoryDatabase("DemoApp", memoryDatabaseRoot)
                        .EnableServiceProviderCaching(false));
    }
}
```

The simplest solution is to change the **Auto generated** `DbContext` and remove the `.HasNoKey()` config, but it would be removed each time the schema structure will be generated with `EF Core PowerTools`.

**Search for other solutions which would not require changes in **Auto generated** files**
Found: [how to test keyless entity - github discussion planned for EF Core 5](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/898) and [stackoverflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182040/how-to-extend-dbcontext-with-partial-class-and-partial-onmodelcreating-method-in/58532261#)

**Attemp #2** - Try to create another `DbContext` and override the entity setup by adding explicitly a key when `Database.IsInMemory`

```
public class TestingDemoDbContext : DemoDbContext {
    public TestingDemoDbContext(){}

    public TestingDemoDbContext(DbContextOptions<DemoDbContext> options): base(options){}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ViewDemoAccountInfo>(entity => {
            if (Database.IsInMemory()) {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.AccountType, e.AccountStartDate });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In `BaseIntegrationTest` use the "extended" `TestingDemoDbContext` in `ConfigureInMemoryDatabases` method.

```
internal static class IntegrationExtensions {
    public static void ConfigureInMemoryDatabases(this IServiceCollection services, InMemoryDatabaseRoot memoryDatabaseRoot) {
        services.AddDbContext<TestingDemoDbContext>(options => 
                 options.UseInMemoryDatabase("DemoApp", memoryDatabaseRoot)
                        .EnableServiceProviderCaching(false));
    }
}
```

The test is similar, with a small difference: `var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TestingDemoDbContext>();`

**Result** - strange, but it throws `The string argument 'connectionString' cannot be empty.` - even I do use the InMemoryDatabase

**Attemp #3** - Try to use the `OnModelCreatingPartial` method to add a Key for that keyless entity.
So, in the same namespace with the Regular `DbContext`, create the partial `DbContext` meant to enrich the existing config

```
namespace Demo.Data.Entities {
    public partial class DemoDbContext : DbContext {
        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder builder) {
            builder.Entity<ViewDemoAccountInfo>(entity => {
                // try to set a key when Database.IsInMemory() 
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.AccountType, e.AccountStartDate }));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** - `The key { e.AccountType, e.AccountStartDate } cannot be added to keyless type 'ViewDemoAccountInfo'.`

Any hints on how to add some mock data for Keyless entities (mapped to **Sql View**), with **InMemoryDatabase**, for testing purpose (with `XUnit`) would be grateful appreciated.

As well, if something is wrong or is considered bad practice in the setup I have listed here - would appreciate to receive improvement suggestions.

Comment: Any luck with this one?

Comment: in this PR: https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/pull/2745/files is he follow-up of the discussion concerning the issue originally posted here: https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/898

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to share the solution I ended up using for this in case anyone else comes across here.

In my model class, I added a [NotMapped] field named 'UnitTestKey'.

#### KeylessTable.cs

```
[Table("KeylessTable", Schema = "dbo")]
public class KeylessTable
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int UnitTestKey { get; set; }

    [Column("FakeColName")]
    public string FakeColumn { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext class, I use IHostEnvironment and used that to set HasKey() or HasNoKey() depending on if we are in the "Unit Testing" environment.

> This example is using .NET 5. If using .NET Core 3.1 like in the original question, you would want to use IWebHostEnvironment.

#### ContextClass.cs

```
public class ContextClass : DbContext
{
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _environment;

    public ContextClass(DbContextOptions<ContextClass> options, IHostEnvironment environment) : base(options)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public DbSet<KeylessTable> KeylessTable => Set<KeylessTable>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<KeylessTable>(entity => {
            if (_environment.EnvironmentName == "UnitTesting")
                entity.HasKey(x => x.UnitTestKey);
            else
                entity.HasNoKey();
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my unit test, I mock the environment and set the name to be "UnitTesting".

#### UnitTest.cs

```
[Fact]
public async void GetKeylessTable_KeylessTableList()
{
    // Arrange
    var environment = new Mock<IHostEnvironment>();
    environment.Setup(e => e.EnvironmentName).Returns("UnitTesting");

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextClass>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;
    var contextStub = new ContextClass(options, environment.Object);
    contextStub.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    contextStub.Database.EnsureCreated();

    contextStub.Set<KeylessTable>().AddRange(_keylessTablelMockData);
    contextStub.SaveChanges();

    var repository = new Repo(contextStub);

    // Act
    var response = await repository.GetKeylessData();

    // Assert
    response.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_keylessTablelMockData);
}
```